# Preact apollo client showing error while rendering data from server side using graphql

Tags: mongodb, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, preact

I am trying to make a todo list application using graphql and mongodb on server side and preact and apollo client server on the client side
The data from the database is being fetched to the client side but its not getting rendered and an error is show in the console which says 
**Error: Argument of undefined passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL DocumentNode. You may need to use 'graphql-tag' or another method to convert your operation into a document bundle.js**

my **list** component looks like this

```
import {h, Component} from 'preact';
import style from './style';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import {Query, Mutation} from 'react-apollo';

const GET_TODOS = gql`
        query {
            todos{
                id
                content
                isChecked
            }
        }
    `;

    const REMOVE_TODO = gql`
    mutation RemoveTodo($id: Int!) {
        removeTodo(id:$id) {
            id
            content
            isChecked
        }
    }
    `;

    const List = () => (
        <Query query={GET_TODOS}>
            {({loading, error, data}) => {
                if(loading) return <p>Loading...</p>
                if(error) return <p>Error</p>

                console.log(data.todos)

                return(
                    <ul class={style.todolist}>
                        {
                            data.todos.map((todo) => (
                                <li>
                                    {todo.content}

                                    <Mutation 
                                        muation={REMOVE_TODO}
                                        update={(cache, {data: {removeTodo}})=> {
                                            const results = cache.readQuery({query: GET_TODOS});

                                            console.log(removeTodo);
                                            console.log(results);

                                            cache.writeQuery({
                                                query: GET_TODOS,
                                                data: { todos: removeTodo}
                                            });
                                        }}
                                    >
                                    {(removeTodo, {data}) => (
                                        <button onClick={e => {
                                            removeTodo({variables: {id: todo.id}});
                                        }}>
                                        Remove</button>
                                    )}
                                    </Mutation>
                                </li>
                            )
                        )
                    }
                </ul> 
            );
        }}
    </Query>
    )

    export default List;
```

Here when i am doing **console.log(data.todos)** it's showing the data that has been fetched from the server side in the console.
[Logged data that has been fetched from the server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Q5G.png)

but soon after this a error is being showed in the console.
[Error show in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mike.png)

This **list** component is being called in my **home** component, which looks like this

```
import {h, Component} from 'preact';
import style from './style';
import List from '../list';
import ListHeader from '../listHeader';
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo';

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class={style.home}>
                <h1>Todo List</h1>
                <ListHeader />
                <List />
                </div>
        ) 
    }
}

export default Home
```

The **home** component is being called in my **app** component which looks like this

```
import { h, Component } from 'preact';

import Header from './header';

// Code-splitting is automated for routes
import Home from './home';

import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";

const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
});

export default class App extends Component {

    /** Gets fired when the route changes.
     *  @param {Object} event       "change" event from [preact-router](http://git.io/preact-router)
     *  @param {string} event.url   The newly routed URL
     */
    // handleRoute = e => {
    //  this.currentUrl = e.url;
    // };

    render() {
        return (
            <ApolloProvider client={client}>
                <div id="app">
                <Header />
                <Home />
            </div>
            </ApolloProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

The complete repository for this can be found here [todo app github repository link](https://github.com/prasunk96/todoQL)

Comment: I guess it's this typo here: `muation={REMOVE_TODO}` where you misstyped `mutation` and the component receives undefined for the property instead. Type systems save lives :(